# App component not working when importing angular 2 http module

Tags: http, angular, angular-cli

I created a project using angular cli, when I try to import http on my service from @angular/http I receive a blank page on chrome although I only try to pass a string from the service to the app component. It seems to be a problem with the library because when I remove the constructor with the http dependency from the ImageService the app works.
I looked on multiple solutions on the web but couldn't find the right one.

the service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class ImagesService {

  private url = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/';

  constructor(private http:Http) {
  }

  getImage2():Promise<string> {
    return Promise.resolve("blah");
  }
```

app component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ImagesService} from "./images.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: ` <h1>My First Angular 2 {{ name }} App</h1>`,
  providers: [ImagesService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  name : string;

  constructor(private ImagesService: ImagesService) { }

  ngOnInit() : void {
    this.setImage();
  }

  setImage(): void {
    this.ImagesService.getImage().then(name => this.name = name);
  }
}
```

main (I thought I should import http also here but received errors)

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent, environment } from './app/';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Comment: are you getting any actual error on your html page in the dev tools console? if you dont see it on your first load, try to refresh the page and see if an error occurs then

Comment: In order to read error output open the Console in your browser. The shortcut is usually `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `j` on Windows.

Comment: hi, I checked the console and this is what I got: angular 2 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Http!

Comment: (1) Base on your main.ts, you seems to be using RC4. According to memory, http need to be bootstrapped in main.ts. However I can't find any code now. (2) Consider migrating your apps to 2.0.0.